# Polish postfix notation not calculating, always showing '0' as result

Tags: c, stack, postfix-notation

I'm studying a stack-based polish notation calculator, which reads an infix expression, validates if the parentheses are correct, converts it to postfix and then evaluates it for the end result. But I am having some problems with the evaluation part, the code is skipping an entire 'while' loop (I've added some printf's to it, to find out exactly where it stops working), and always shows the end result as '0'.

This is for my data structure studies. Everything seems to be working fine, but the evaluation part. I've tried adding some variables, but it did not work.

```
void postfix(){
    int i = 0, op1, op2;
    char ch;
    int p =-1;
    char exp[20];
    char *e, x;
    e = exp;

    printf("Input the expression again: ");
    scanf("%s", &exp);
    printf("\nThe postfix expression is: ");

    while(*e != 0){
        if(isalnum(*e)){
            printf("%c",*e);
            post[++p]=*e;
        } else if(*e == '(')
            push(*e);
        else if(*e == ')'){
            while((x = pop()) != '('){
                printf("%c", x);
                post[++p]=x;
            }
        } else{
            while(priority(pilha[top]) >= priority(*e)){
                char a;
                a= pop();
                printf("%c",a);
                post[++p]=a;
            }
            push(*e);
        }
        e++;
     }

    while(top != -1){
        char avaliada;
        avaliada = pop();

        printf("%c",avaliada);
        post[++p] = avaliada;
    }
}

void evaluation(){
    int i = 0, op1, op2;
    char ch;
    int p =-1;
    char exp[20];
    char *e, x;
    e = exp;

    postfix();

    while(i != (p+1)){
        ch=post[i];
        i++;

        if(isdigit(ch)){
            xpush(ch - '0');
        } else{
            op2=xpop();
            op1=xpop();

            switch(ch){
                case '+':xpush(op1+op2);break;
                case '-':xpush(op1-op2);break;
                case '*':xpush(op1*op2);break;
                case '/':xpush(op1/op2);break;
            }
        }

     printf("\n\nResult: %d\n",s[xtop]);
}
```

For example, if I input the '2-1' expression in the console, I expect it to show the postfix notation, which would be '21-', and the calculated result, which would be '1', but the actual output is '0'.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but for `scanf` the format specifier `"%s"` expects the pointer to the first character or an array, of type `char *`. In your case that would be `&exp[0]` (which is what plain `exp` by itself decays to). The expression `&exp` is a pointer to the array itself, and have the type `char (*)[20]`, which is semantically very different from what's expected.

Comment: As for your problem, now seems like a very good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: And a general tip: Stop using global variables! If you need multiple functions to access something, pass it as arguments. And if you want a function to return something, have it actually return that.

Comment: Finally, please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Oh, and a final hint about a possible reason for your problem: How many variables named `p` do you have? How are they related (if related at all)?

Comment: `while(i != (p+1))` never executes the body. `i == 0`, `p == -1`, hence `p+1 == 0`. So the loop ends immediately.

Comment: Thank you for all the advises. Indeed it's time for me to learn how to debug the code. But in the end a friend gave me a tip about passing 'p' variable as parameter and it worked